# Consulta SQLquery con Join y 3 tablas

Tags: sql

tengo un problema que no se como resvolver.
Tengo 3 tablas:
tabla1 citas: ID_Cita, fecha, ID_Paciente.
Tabla2 paciente: nombre, ID_Paciente, ID_Departamento,
tabla2 departamento: ID_Departamento, nombre_departamento.

Necesito obtener el número de citas por cada departamento. Por ejemplo, esta el paciente "X" el cual esta asociado a un departamento---> ID_Departamento. 
Luego este solicita una cita la cual esta asociada a un paciente---> ID_Paciente.

Answer (score 0):

Debes relacionar las tres tables ya sea en el where o usando un inner join y usar una funcion que te cuente lo agrupado por paciente y departamento

```
**

select paciente.nombre, departamento.nombre_departamento, count(citas.ID_Cita) as total_citas from citas 
inner join paciente on paciente.ID_Paciente = citas.ID_Paciente
inner join departamento on departamento.ID_Departamento = paciente.ID_Departamento
group by paciente.nombre, departamento.nombre_departamento
```

**

Answer (score 0):

obtienes la cantidad de cada cita en relación con el paciente,
aplicas un inner join  entre la tabla paciente y departamento

ejemplo:

```
SELECT count(select count(*) from citas where citas.ID_Paciente=paciente.ID_Paciente) as num_citas 
,paciente.nombre
,departamento.nombre_departamento
FROM paciente
inner join departamento on departamento.ID_Departamento=paciente.ID_Departamento
```